# Kolmogorov's example of a measurable function not (generally) differentiable

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory

In [1, page 7], the author says.

> Kolmogorov showed that if the function $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos 3^n x}{3^n}$$ has a finite or infinite generalized derivative on a set of positive measure, then the function is *nonmeasurable*.

Where can I find a proof/explanation of this result (and/or other similar results) **in English**? The reference doesn't have to be to Kolmogorov's orignal paper; for example, a modern exposition would suffice (and might very well be better).

[1] A. N. Shiryaev, "Andrei Nikolaevich Kolmogorov", Theory of Probability
and Applications, vol 34, no. 1, 1988.

Comment: Note that I also posted this question on math.SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103000/kolmogorovs-example-of-a-measurable-function-not-generally-differentiable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A translation in english is in "Selected Works of A.N. Kolmogorov I" : ["On the possibility of a general definition of derivative, integral and summation of divergent series"](http://books.google.fr/books?id=ikN59GkYJKIC&pg=PA33)  (page 33 and 34).

Answer (score 1):

Kolmogorov's original paper:

'Sur la possibilite de la definition generale de la derivee, de l'integrale et de la sommation des series divergentes', C.R. Acad. Sci. Paris 180(1925), 362-364.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose that reference is in French, which I cannot read. Do you know if there's an English translation?

Comment: Yes, see:
V.M. Tikhomirov (Ed.): Selected works of A.N. Kolmogorov, Vol.1, Kluwer, pp.51-52